# Bootstrap modal won't show up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

My bootstrap (3.0.2) modal won't show up. I've tried different buttons, links and all that but it simply won't show up. I appreciate any help!

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">Purchase</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="purchaseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="purchaseLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="purchaseLabel">Purchase</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    sup?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Here's a screenshot of the warnings in the console.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
The button and the modal are located inside a container. Maybe this could help on your path to a solution?

Comment: Load page --> Right Click --> Inspect Element (Google Chrome). When you click the Link to open model, see if there are any Errors in Console. Post snapshot of Error

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://bootply.com/94899 Any browser console errors? Can you remove `js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js`? and test?

Comment: @Skelly I tried but I had no luck. Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put jquery and bootstraps javascript files path in the head of you html.
I was having the same problem and this worked  for me.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- put first the jquery path, otherwise the bootstrap.js won't work-->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Hope it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

This code is working fine.
You have an javaScript error somewhere:

Working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal">Purchase</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="purchaseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="purchaseLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="purchaseLabel">Purchase</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    sup?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This didn't work. Thanks for your reply though. I tried adding `onclick="$('#purchaseModal').modal('show');"` to the button and that made it work. What could be the issue?

Comment: I cant't tell, because the code I put here is working for me, in your code you have added twice jQuery, maybe is this? Did you try exactly my code, just put the code in a .html file and run it then try to see whats is different with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding this line of JQuery to the bottom of the page;

```
<script>
    $("[data-toggle='modal']").modal();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this one line of code to the head solved the issue for me.

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. when i add this code :

```
let postBody = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
```

modal will not show up . and when i remove it the modal appears.

Answer (score 0):

It started working for me if I added the code down below to the end of my layout.html before the body tag ends.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```